# Avoiding memory leaks with events

Tags: c#, winforms

```
class Subscriber
{
    private Publisher _publisher;

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        _publisher = new Publisher();
        _publisher.SomeEvent += HandleEvent;
    }

    void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    void FireEvent()
    {
        SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Do I need to detach `HandleEvent` from `SomeEvent` to avoid memory leak?
Subscriber lives longer than Publisher, so my understanding is that when Publisher gets disposed, it will also clear all event handlers from `SomeEvent`, so there shouldn't be any references left. Am I right?

Comment: Who is Disposing the Publisher? I expect that the Subscriber is doing it, am I correct?

Comment: @Kzrystof - Hopefully, nobody is Disposing anything. There are no resources in sight.

Comment: @Signum If the actual program is bigger, there is a chance old Publisher instances could fire the event, they could be kept in memory and the Subscriber's HandleEvent can be called by all these old Publisher instances. If you expect to handle only the _publisher's event, be careful that is always the case and consider unsubscribing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Subscriber lives longer than Publisher

That means you are OK, no need to complicate things with an unsubscribe.

The statement `_publisher.SomeEvent += HandleEvent;` creates a (somewhat hidden) reference from _publisher to its owner. That would prevent the owning Subscriber from being collected, but only when the publisher outlives it.

Since _publisher is private, the cleanup is implicit. You do not have to (should 
not) add IDisposable here. That is, not for managing the events.

And since you tagged this WinForms: all those eventhandlers (eg Button1_Click) all create references from a Control to the owning Form, no need for cleanup there either.

Comment: If Publisher is ready to get cleaned up, won't it still have a reference to Subscriber through SomeEvent which will prevent it from being GCd?

Comment: It has an outgoing reference, not a problem. Only being referenced can save you from the GC. When you set `_publisher = null;` the old publisher becomes eligible for collection.

Comment: That makes sense. A subscriber dictating how long a publisher can live simply by not unsubbing seems like a bad idea.